# FirebaseのAuthenticationでメールアドレスがすでに登録されているか確認するには

Tags: database, kotlin, firebase

FirebaseのAuthenticationでメールアドレスがすでに登録されているか確認するにはどうすればよいですか？
言語はKotlinです

Answer (score 1):

[fetchSignInMethodsForEmail](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchsigninmethodsforemail) を使ってできます。password認証を使っている場合は、登録されていると `["password"]` のように返ってくると思います。